# Concrete example for the definition of parallel inheritance

Tags: oop, design-patterns

While reading *Dive Into Design Patterns* by Alexander Shvets, I stumbled across the following statement in the section "Favor Composition Over Inheritance":

> Trying to reuse code through inheritance can lead to creating parallel inheritance hierarchies

According to [this](https://refactoring.guru/smells/parallel-inheritance-hierarchies) site the definition of parallel inheritance is the situation in which subclassing a class requires creating yet another subclass elsewhere. I'm interested in knowing what would be this kind of scenario, where we'd have to subclass all over the place, and further more the *why* of it: why would we have to create the subclass elsewhere? Does the need arise from the context and the problem we are trying to solve, or is it induced by the structure of the (at least) two class hierarchies and composition between them? While [here](https://wiki.c2.com/?ParallelInheritanceHierarchies) is an attempt to give a mathematical definition for the parallel inheritance, the need for the implication is not clear to me.

Comment: my understanding is that you need a class that has to implement multiple functions, so it has to inherit from more than one class or alternatively multiple different classes need to implement common functionality, so these super classes create their own hierarchies "parallel" to each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand this like that. Imagine you have

```cs
public abstract class CarBase
{
    // all cars run on liquid fuel, right? This is 1955
    public decimal FuelVolume { get; set; }
}
```

Then you inherit this and create your `PUTruck`, `SportsCar`, `Sedan` etc

Suddenly, this is 2022 and you have Electric car. You will probably do

```cs
public abstract class ElectricCarBase : CarBase
{
    public decimal ChargeVolume { get; set; }
}
```

^^ this will come with all the nastiness of unused and unneeded properties, bunch of noise, like Antifreeze and fuel lines. And you endup in parallel inheritance. You will need to create all sort of adapters to support all this..

**Enter** "Composition Over Inheritance"

```cs
public abstract class CarBase
{
    public List<IFuelProvider> FuelSources { get; set; }
}

public interface IFuelProvider 
{
    
    public FuelType TypeOfFuel { get; set; }

    public string MeasureUnit { get; set; }

    public int FuelUnits { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can support Gas, Electric or Hybrid

This is my understanding. Welcome to disagree

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit lost on the example (I'm not a java programmer). Could you go over one more time why all the nastiness results from us subclassing the abstract class `CarBase`with `ElectricCarBase`, which has its own new method?

Comment: @EpsilonAway Because idea of polymorphism is that you have 2 types that act the same while doing different things. In this example, it is obvious that Electric car has no liquid fuel and cannot act the same. You're going to endup with `if (instance is ElecticCar) instance .doThis; else instance.doThat;` While should of been `instance.JustDoIt()`. In other words, in this example, it is obvious that you have parallel inheritance where all electric cars have a different set of behaviors from the liquid fuel cars. And you would have to cast them every time for a specific behavior.

Comment: @EpsilonAway
With "Composition Over Inheritance" your class will always exhibit same behavior because it will subscribe to different services and unify their use. It is like, if you have your wife, you always get same cooking. But if you subscribe to a chef, you can replace him any time you need to. With the wife, you bound for life. But chef is a subcontractor. Who cares if the new one a vegetarian. But if your wife turns into a vegetarian, you are going into hell.

Comment: @EpsilonAway, the idea is that CarBase and ElectricCarBase need both to implement same common functionality (eg drive, stop, turn, etc) but this common functionality now has to be created in parallel both in CarBase and ElectricCarBase, maybe in future also in other class. But with composition, common functionality is implemented only once

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to inheritance, it seems we can always take examples from the Animal Kingdom. So we have a class hierarchy of `Animal` like this.

```
interface Animal {
    void eat(Food someFood);
}
```

But every `Animal` has its own special `Food`. So when we subclass `Animal` with `Dog` we need to subclass `Food` with `DogFood` and when we subclass `Animal` with `Cat` we need to subclass `Food` with `CatFood` and so on.

Parallel hierarchies can occur naturally in a problem domain, in which case it may be sensible to model them the same way in code. But parallel hierarchies can also occur artificially in a solution domain, and that verbosity may be undesirable.

On StackOverflow, the syntactic question that often arises from this scenario is, *how do I make sure my Animal doesn't eat the wrong Food?*